# Change OG metatags from Liferay portlet

Tags: liferay, facebook-opengraph, meta, spring-portlet-mvc

I want to change OG metatags based on request params. I use Liferay 6.0.6 and Spring Portlet MVC 3.1.2.

If user comes to URL `example.com?param=value1`, I want to set:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/image1.png">
```

If user comes to `example.com?param=value2`, I want to set:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/image2.png">
```

Liferay can set title, subtitle, description and keywords through `PortalUtil`. Can I set these OG metatags somehow similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to have a look at `<liferay-util:html-top>`. It's discussed e.g. here http://www.liferay.com/web/samuel.kong/blog/-/blogs/adding-a-javascript-to-every-page

Comment: Great! But if I use this, it can only add new stuff to `head`, but not replace existing.

Comment: you can replace existing by using custom jsp bags 
see: https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/jsp-overrides-using-custom-jsp-bag

Answer (score 2):

You have more options.

- You can write ServicePreAction where you calculate the right image value and then use int theme template
- You can include logic into the theme (create your own service) and calculate the value there.

I would use the first approach.